# How to create dynamic list on a website

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I'm looking for a way to create a dynamic episodes list in html css javascript that understand in which episode the user is and add the "active" class to the li element of the list.

Let me show you an exemple : 
[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImL21.png)

Thanks you :)

Answer (score 0):

This might help. Call the method `changeEpisode` when the video ends.

```js
document.getElementById("video").addEventListener("ended", changeEpisode, false);
function changeEpisode()
{
    var elem = $("#episode_list li.active");
    $(elem).removeClass("active");
    $(elem).next().addClass("active");
    $("#video").attr("src",$(elem).next().data("src"));
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<video height="200px" width="200px" controls autoplay src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" id="video"></video>
<ul class="list-group" id="episode_list">
  <li class="list-group-item active" data-src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4">Episode 1</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" data-src="https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/devstories.mp4">Episode 2</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" data-src="https://archive.org/download/Popeye_forPresident/Popeye_forPresident_512kb.mp4">Episode 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I want that the active class is added to the list even before user played the video.

Comment: Initially the active class set to `e1` so `e1` is playing. After `e1` finishes, `e2` plays and `e2` gets active class.
I just shown an example to set the active class after video ends. After video finishes set the src of the video to another video so it plays the `e3` video.

Comment: It works independently of the video, I think it analyzes the link or the text of the page and it looks what is the element that looks the most but I do not.... please take a look in live [link](https://www.anime-gate.com/animes-streaming/hunter-x-hunter-2011-03-vostfr)

Comment: See no one in the world will analyze the line text or any thing in the webpage. They just store the episode number using the localstorage/sessionstorge in client or in server side. When the user reloads the page or comes after some days, they get the last episode watched from those. You may want to read these. [Client storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)